# How to get UITableviewcell value on click on button

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to get UITableviewCell value on click of Login button. When user press on Login button then i want to fetch first cell(Email) and second cell(password) value. Please help me.

[image]

Thanks!
Shailesh

Comment: Both are text field ?

Comment: Yes, Both are textfield... Actually i've created custom tableview cell with textbox.

Comment: Hi, if email and password should be a text field that is added inside cell then you can fetch values from both cell otherwise method can not identify that which fields value you want to fetch inside cell.

Comment: See my given answer bellow in which loginBtnTouchUpInside method is  fetching values from email and password

Comment: See my given answer..i hope it may help you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try to use this one.I hope it may help you. But you should assign tag 1 to email and 2 to password text field.

```
-(IBAction)loginBtnPressed:(IBAction)sender
{
   UITableViewCell *emailCell = [self.tblView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]]; 
                                  UITableViewCell *passwordCell = [self.tblView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0]] ;//pass
    UITextField *emailTxtFLd = (UITextField *)[emailCell viewWithTag:1];
    UITextField *passwordTxtFLd = (UITextField *)[passwordCell viewWithTag:2];

    NSLog(@"Email : %@",emailTxtFLd.text);
    NSLog(@"Password : %@",passwordTxtFLd.text);
}
```

Comment: Hi Dharmbir, Thank you for your reply. I've tried your code but i am getting error "property tblview not found on object of type textboxViewController". I am new in IOS so, please explain in detail. Thanks lot

Comment: connect your tableview with IBOutlet.My answer is perfect and its working proper.You make property for table view and synthesize in .m file.

Comment: make like this and connect your table view with this and write this line in .h file ... @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tblView;

Comment: Hi Dharmbir,
I've added property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tblLoginView;  in .h file and @synthesize tblLoginView = _tblLoginView; added in .m file then error is resolved but null value is coming in textfield.

am i missing something? Please help me. Thanks lot.

Comment: Hi Dharmbir,
I've done few changes in your code and it works for me. UITableViewCell *emailCell = [self.tblLoginView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]]; UITextField *myTextField = (UITextField *)[emailCell viewWithTag:-1]; NSString *emailString = [myTextField text]; Thanks lot for your help.

Comment: Your welcome my dear and if you got your answer so accept this answer.

Comment: Thanks Dharmbir, I've did small changes in your code and accepted your answer. Thanks lot.

Comment: Most welcome and you knw you have different name for your tableview so it should be changed.

Comment: Hi Dharmbir, Is it possible for you to share your email with me ? I've some more confusions that i want to discuss with you. Thanks :)

Comment: but dear i'm not online in office. "chaudhary.dharmbir@gmail.com"..Jst chilll ....mje kro yar.....

Answer (score 2):

You do one thing, when you add textFiled as a subView to the cell, set a tag to the textFiled like as given,

```
[textField setTag:-1];
```

And when you want to get the text from the textFiled, follow the steps below.

```
// Getting email
CustomCell *tableCell = (CustomCell*)[myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];

UITextField *myTextField = (UITextField *)[tableCell viewWithTag:-1];

NSString *emailString = [myTextField text];
NSLog(@"~~~~ email: %@", emailString);

// Getting Password
tableCell = [myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0]];

myTextField = (UITextField *)[tableCell viewWithTag:-1];

NSString *passwordString = [myTextField text];
NSLog(@"~~~~ password: %@", passwordString);
```

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: Hi Augustine,

I've done few changes in your code and it works for me.
 UITableViewCell *emailCell = [self.tblLoginView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
    UITextField *myTextField = (UITextField *)[emailCell viewWithTag:-1];
    
    NSString *emailString = [myTextField text];
Thanks lot for your kind help.

Answer (score 1):

Since both cells are visible, you can just ask for them this way:

```
UITableViewCell *emailCell = [myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] //email
UITableViewCell *passwordCell = [myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0] //password
```

Then assuming both UITableViewCell have a property in their header exposed for the UILabel you can do:

```
emailCell.myLabel.text //Value of the text in the cell
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for your kind reply but it is showing error like No known class methode for cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: @NareshChauhan You're welcome. This is not a class method it is an instance method, you can call it on your instance of UITableView, here is the documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 1):

If email and password has allocated then You can directly access them in your IIBAction method like that

in your .h file delcare this to email and password UItextfield

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    UITextField *email;
    UITextField *pass;
}
```

Now alloc and add it in your cell

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    email = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 140)];
    pass = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 140)];
}



 // Table View Data Source methods

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return  2;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];

    if(cell==nil)
    {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    if(indexPath.row==0)
    {
        [cell addSubview:email];
    }
    if(indexPath.row==1)
    {
        [cell addSubview:pass];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Now apply this IBAction on your login button

```
- (IBAction)loginBtnTouchUpInside:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"email ==== %@",email.text);
    NSLog(@"pass ==== %@",pass.text);

    NSString *strEmail = email.text; 
    NSString *strPassword = pass.text;
}
```

I hope this is works for you

Comment: Wow :) It's work like as charm :) Thanks i learn something new from your answer :) Thank you very much chandan :) Thanks lot

Comment: Welcome @Naresh and please vote if you really like this code. Thanks

Comment: Hi Chandan, Is there no any other methode in which we directly fetch cell 1 and cell 2 value? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)ActivateLogin{


NSIndexPath *tmpIndexPath0 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
NSIndexPath *tmpIndexPath1 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0];

CustomCell *cellCopy0 =(CustomCell*) [tableViewName cellForRowAtIndexPath:tmpIndexPath0];
CustomCell *cellCopy1 =(CustomCell*) [tableViewName cellForRowAtIndexPath:tmpIndexPath1];


NSString *strEmail = @""; NSString *strPassword = @"";

strEmail = cellCopy0.tf.text;
strPassword = cellCopy1.tf.text;

if(![strEmail isEqualToString:@""] && ![strPassword isEqualToString:@""]){

... //Do what you want to do with the data

}
else{
//Alert user to enter credentials
}

}
```

Comment: Hi Mohith, Thank you very much for your reply. Email and password are 2 cell of UITableView so, i want to fetch the value of UITableView Cell. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is, save the textField value in a separate string in textField delegate like below.

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
 stringEmail = textField.text;
}
```

and use the string value for further process.Do it for both by setting tag.

Thank You.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. Actully Email and password are cell of UITableView and i want to fetch UITableview cell text.

Comment: Whatever it is, but you are assigning UITextField value to table cell, Right? So you can get table cell value from textfield itself.